# data in the row is not deleted from table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

when I click delete it doesn't delete or edit the row I created
so my **MainActivity** is

```
    package com.frolicfreak.bhushan.memo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.frolicfreak.bhushan.memo.DatabaseHelper.Table_Name;
import static com.frolicfreak.bhushan.memo.DatabaseHelper.col1;
import static com.frolicfreak.bhushan.memo.DatabaseHelper.col2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

FloatingActionButton fab;
DatabaseHelper mydb;

ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb =new DatabaseHelper(this);

    fab= (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ArrayList<String> theList =new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data= mydb.getAllData();
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(null);

    if (data.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
           // int count= mydb.updaterow(getString(col2),EditText.)
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            int count=mydb.deleterow(getString(item.getItemId()));
            onResume();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent= new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

My **DataBasehelper** class

```
package com.frolicfreak.bhushan.memo;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by BHUSHAN on 24-08-2017.
*/

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String Database_Name = "Memo.db";
public static final String Table_Name = "Memo";
public static final String col1 = "ID";
public static final String col2 = "data";

//DatabaseHelper mydb;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, Database_Name, null, 1);
    //mydb=new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + Table_Name + "(ID integer primary key autoincrement, data text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + Table_Name);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String data, String Data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(col2, Data);
    long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);
    if (result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.query(Table_Name,new String[]{col1},new String(col2),null,null,null,null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int index= cursor.getColumnIndex(col1);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(index));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return taskList;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Table_Name, null);
    return res;
}


public int deleterow(String col1) {
    String whereClause = "ID = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(col1)};

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int count = db.delete(Table_Name, whereClause, whereArgs);
    db.close();
    return count;
}

 /* public int updaterow(String oldname, String newdata){
    SQLiteDatabase db= mydb.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DatabaseHelper.col2,newdata);
    String[] whereargs={oldname};
    int count = db.update(Table_Name,cv, DatabaseHelper.col2+"=?" , whereargs);
    return count;
}*/
 }
```

my **Main2Activity** class where I edit and insert data

```
 package com.frolicfreak.bhushan.memo;

 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;

EditText Data;
FloatingActionButton add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    add =(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.add);

    AddData();
}

public void AddData(){
    add.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = 
 db.insertData(Data.getText().toString(),
                             Data.getText().toString() );
                    if (isInserted==true)
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"data 
 inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,"data not 
 inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

}
```

please help me I'm new to programming so I'm trying to learn here
thankyou in advance
and I actually need help with editing and saving the data too I wrote the code but I saved it in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete function is working fine according to the code. Check the return is greater than 0 or not.

But you won't be able to see the changes in the ListView because you have to populate the list again.

Set an `CursorAdapter` since you're using a database to link to the listview and use `CursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`()

Or create a method that will recreate the listview when a delete occurs.

```
ArrayList<String> COUNTRIES = new ArrayList<>();
public void refreshView() {

    MyDatabase database = new MyDatabase(ViewList.this);

    Cursor cursor = database.fetchAllData();

    COUNTRIES.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(database.COL1));
        COUNTRIES.add(temp);
    }
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

Comment: can you tell me what should I pass in ` case R.id.delete:
            int count=mydb.deleterow(getString(item.getItemId()));`
or `getString(item.getitemId());`will work
and how should I link the cursor adaptor and where

Comment: `mydb.deleterow()` takes a string as the parameter. The name of the column you want to delete. So you have to pass a string as the argument in `mydb.deleterow`. ALthough i am a bit unclear about you problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: I want to delete the row using column id and I dont know how to pass the primary key (ID) in `mydb.deleterow()`
or how the app will get the primary key or id of the data

Comment: It's better if you pass a string to the delete function. Get the string you want to delete from the user using an EditText and pass it on to the `mydb.deleterow(edittext.getText().toString());`

Comment: what should I write in if statement if its is greater then 0 and else statement too

Comment: `if(mydb.deleterow("your string")>0)
 //TOAST Deleted 
else
//TOAST Not deleted`
since `db.delete(Table_Name, whereClause, whereArgs);` returns the number of rows deleted from the database it is presumed that if it returns more than 0, a certain row is deleted. Else it has not.

Comment: I got this main error after I clicked delete
`'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Mention id of the edittext in the XML file using `android:id="@+id/edit"` tag and then initialize the EditText using `EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);`

Comment: And please mark up the comments and answers you find helpful.

Comment: Have you initialized it in the OnCreate method?

Comment: yes, I actually did it and still getting this error

Comment: Please post your EditText code here from the MainActivity and XML files.

Comment: **MainActivity**
https://pastebin.com/YcHEb9SN

edit Xml file
https://pastebin.com/vqyDehi8

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1H07BfL0 - java, https://pastebin.com/W4gE4FXT - XML

Comment: Sir can you please explain what you have replaced in the java file or the xml file because I didn't understood that and the error still persists
and actually I think I sent you the wrong xml file I sen you the xml file in which I edit the text 
so here's the xml file of the **MainActivity**
https://pastebin.com/7UUBUN5Y
thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

When deleting, you are calling this

```
int count=mydb.deleterow(getString(item.getItemId()));
onResume();
```

You are not passing the id of selected item, but you are passing menu item's string fetched by getString(...) method, which is weird. There are so much unused code in your class.

I advice you to work on [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and ListView.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good programming pattern to call onResume() method. You should extract it to different method and call it in onResume().

Anyway, in this case `notifyDataSetChanged()` is a solution what you are looking for.

Comment: where should I add that?
how to extract it on onResume()

Comment: I suggest, every time you come back to activity, you want to refresh your ListView with actual items, right? If you really need it, put yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() into onResume() method and it will works fine.